# Plotting static mock data in Grafana with grafanalib

Tags: python, grafana

I have been playing with grafanalib for a while and it is easy to display data from well known sources. In this case the following example tries to Draw a timeseries graph including a dictionary with the actual time series data, but is not displaying the data.

```
from grafanalib.core import (
Dashboard, Stat, Target, GridPos, Template, Graph, Templating, Time, Repeat, OPS_FORMAT,    RowPanel,
    SHORT_FORMAT,
    SqlTarget,
    YAxes,
    YAxis,
    TimeSeries, GaugePanel,

)

import json

# Define your data
data_source = "Dashboard"  
dashboard_title = "Time Series Dashboard examplle"

# Hardcoded time series data
time_series_data = [
    {"timestamp": 1638200000000, "value": 10},
    {"timestamp": 1638203600000, "value": 15},
    {"timestamp": 1638207200000, "value": 12},
    # Add more data points as needed
]

# Create targets for each time series
targets = [

    Target(
        expr=f'value({value["value"]}) + timestamp({value["timestamp"]})',
        legendFormat=f'Time Series {index}',
        refId=f'TimeSeries{index}',
    )
    for index, value in enumerate(time_series_data)
]

print(targets)

# Create a simple time series dashboard
dashboard = Dashboard(
    title=dashboard_title,
    uid='5640',
    panels=[
        RowPanel(title="New row", gridPos=GridPos(h=1, w=24, x=0, y=8)),
        TimeSeries(
            title="Random Walk",
            dataSource='default',
            targets=[
                Target(
                    datasource='grafana',
                    expr='example',
                ),
            ],
            gridPos=GridPos(h=8, w=24, x=0, y=9),
        ),
        Graph(
            title='Mocked example static data',
            targets=targets,
            yAxes=YAxes(
                YAxis(format=OPS_FORMAT),
                YAxis(format=SHORT_FORMAT),
            ),
            gridPos=GridPos(h=8, w=24, x=0, y=17),
        ),
    ],    
).auto_panel_ids()
```

Can anyone see what I am missing defining the targets?